# Variadic function f() vs. f(...) in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

What is the difference between the following two variadic function definitions?

```
int f()
{
    /* function definition */
}

int f(...)
{
    /* function definition */
}
```

`f()` is actually defined as a variadic function. I'm also assuming `<stdarg.h>` can be included and used.

Comment: `stdarg.h` is of no use here. The function has to have at least one (plain) parameter for it to work.

Comment: The first one is deprecated since C99, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think you're right that the first one is deprecated. And the second one doesn't compile. So this question needs some work.

Comment: `int f() {...}` *defines* a function taking 0 arguments. This is not the same as `int f();` which *declares* a function taking an unspecified number of arguments.

Comment: @DeiDei What exactly is the feature that was deprecated in C99? Just declaring a function with unspecified parameters or defining a function with empty parameter list? Gcc with the appropriate flags seems to accept both of these features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty parameter list in a function *declaration* indicates that the function takes an unspecified number of arguments (which is not the same as a *variable* number of arguments).  An empty parameter list in a function *definition* (such as in the first definition of `f`) indicates that the function takes *no* arguments.  This is an obsolescent style and should not be used - to indicate that a function takes no parameters, use `void` as the identifier list.

As of C89, a variadic function declarator must have *at least* one fixed parameter, followed by the `...`.  So the second definition of `f` won't work either.

```
int f( void ) // f takes no arguments
{
  // do something
}

int f( T fixed, ... ) // one fixed parameter of some type, additional parameters as needed
{
  // do something
}
```

`printf` is as good an example of a variadic function in the standard library as any - its prototype is

```
int printf( const char *fmt, ... );
```

Comment: If you define a function with `int f() { }`, which, as you say, indicates it takes no arguments, and call it using `f(1, 2)` for example, then what can that lead to? The function will return successfully assuming it doesn't need the actual arguments?

Comment: @bjorn93: The behavior is undefined ([C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.5.2.2/6).